# Laravel - How I Pass Variable Into Blade's Section In One Line?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

how I can pass a variable into the blade command "@section" with the one line approach? I have this:

```
@section('title', 'Hello')
```

Now I want something like

```
@section('title', 'Hello {{ $user->name}} foo') // doesn't work
// or
@section('title', 'Hello ' . {{ $user->name}} . ' foo') // doesn't work
// or
@section('title', 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($user->name) . ' foo') // this works
// or
@section('title')Hello {{ $user->name }} foo @endsection // this works
```

The last two just working fine, but I don't want to use plain php in my blade template and also I don't want to use @endsection for title.

How I can do this? Is there even a possibility or should I go with one of the two solutions?

Comment: Blade is not Twig, it syntax is very close to PHP syntax. You have only directives for main statements (if, for, foreach...), then it's PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use blade echo in blade directives, they're already php code

Remove the double curly braces and wrap it all in double quotes

```
@section('title', "Hello $user->name foo")
```

This is as short as you can get

Comment: Thank you. This seems fine and I have to use plain php.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for

```
@section('title')
 Hello, {{ $user->name}}
@endsection
```

How about this

```
@section('title', 'Hello ' . auth()->user()->name )
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the last one of the 4 examples of mine. But I don't like the "long approach" for the title. It feels like an "overkill" for just few words. It doesn't have a "clear appearance".

Comment: Oh, I missed it.

Comment: This is also plain php. But it seems I don't have a choice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the curly braces like this:

```
@section('title', 'Hello ' . $user->name . ' foo') // This should work
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems that I have to use plain php. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@section('title', 'whatever your string')
```

all you need to do is format a string that support by blade.